# Using map on methods in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some classes in Python:

```
class Class1:
    def method(self):
        return 1
class Class2:
    def method(self):
        return 2
```

and a list `myList` whose elements are all either instances of `Class1` or `Class2`. I'd like to create a new list whose elements are the return values of `method` called on each element of `myList`. I have tried using a "virtual" base class

```
class Class0:
    def method(self):
        return 0
class Class1(Class0):
    def method(self):
        return 1
class Class2(Class0):
    def method(self):
        return 2
```

But if I try `map(Class0.method, myList)` I just get `[0, 0, 0, ...]`. I'm a bit new to Python, and I hear that "duck typing" is preferred to actual inheritance, so maybe this is the wrong approach. Of course, I can do

```
[myList[index].method() for index in xrange(len(myList))]
```

but I like the brevity of `map`. Is there a way to still use `map` for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
map(lambda e: e.method(), myList)
```

But I think this is better:

```
[e.method() for e in myList]
```

PS.: I don't think there is *ever* a need for `range(len(collection))`.

Comment: I think I've run across a few cases where my choices were `range(len(collection))` or using an `enumerate` where I throw away the value portion...  But those cases are *extremely* rare and generally mean that the code needs to be re-factored anyway ...

Comment: Whoops, forgot that you can just loop through the actual objects instead of getting them by index. I do like the `lambda` though, especially since my code is actually for a Scheme interpreter!

Answer (score 4):

The [operator.methodcaller](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) tool is exactly what you're looking for:

```
map(methodcaller("method"), myList)
```

Alternatively you can use a list comprehension:

```
[obj.method() for obj in myList]
```

Comment: This one is used a lot less than `attrgetter` or `itemgetter` but I like it.  +1 from me.

Comment: Methodcaller is more interesting when you pass in arguments in addition to the method name:  ``map(methodcaller('replace', 'big', 'huge'), sentences)``.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen `methodcaller` before.

Answer (score 3):

This is best:

```
[o.method() for o in myList]
```

Map seems to be favored by people pining for Haskell or Lisp, but Python has fine iterative structures you can use instead.